# Simple modules of quantum planes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-rings

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

Let $R := k\langle x,y \rangle/(yx-qxy) (q \in k^*)$.

We often call $R$ a quantum plane.

If $q$ is a primitive $n$-th root, then for any $(\zeta, \xi) \in k^* \times k^*$ we can construct a simple right $R$-module $V$ such that it has $k$-basis $v_i (i \in \mathbb{Z}_n)$ and
$$ v_i.x = \zeta q^i v_i, \quad v_i.y = \xi v_{i+1}
$$
as its module structure.

In Lemma 3.3 in page 203 of [this note](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Esmith/Research/nag.pdf), it is shown that the annihilator of $V$ is $(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n)$ and the ideal is maximal.

It seems that we have $R/(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n) \simeq V$ if we assume the lemma because $(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n)$ is maximal.
In detail, we have a surjection $R/(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n) \rightarrow V$. Then, the kernel seems to be the zero module.
Of course, this argument contradicts the above.

**Question 1.**
Where is the error in the above argument ?

Moreover, there is another description of simple modules of quantum planes in Lemma 4.19 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-015-1407-x).
There, it is shown that $V \simeq R/(x^n-\zeta^n,\xi x- \zeta y)$ implicitly.
Note that isomorphisms between $V$ and $R/(x^n-\zeta^n,\xi x- \zeta y)$ are not constructed in the paper.
(There, the fat points of quantum planes are classified.)

**Question 2.**
How do we construct an explicit isomorphism between them ?

Any comments are welcome.
Thank you.

**Edit1**: I think Question 1 is solved. Thank you very much. The argument in the paragraph immediately preceding Question 1 is wrong (see the comments below).
Please be careful.
We welcome any further comments.

**Edit2**:
We have the same question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507844/simple-modules-of-quantum-planes).
I would appreciate it if you could see it too.

Comment: I don't see why $R/(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n) \simeq V$. The ideal $(x^n-\zeta^n,y^n-\xi^n)$ is maximal as a two-sided ideal, not as a right ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This is my misunderstanding. I didn't pay attention to whether $(x^n-\zeta^n, y^n-\xi^n)$ is a maximal ideal as a two-sided ideal or a right ideal.

Comment: I know that all simple right $R$-module is of the form $R/I$, where $I$ is a maximal right ideal. But, it seems that I misunderstood because of what I wrote in the comment above.

Comment: [Also on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507844/simple-modules-of-quantum-planes). When cross-posting, it is important to link all versions of the question together to prevent duplicating effort.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I also added the link on MSE.